# System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out On certain computer only

Tags: c#, xml, networking, rss

I will preface the code and explanation with the fact that I was able to run this code on the computers that my school has, and I have had multiple friends successfully run the code on their machines.

I have some C# code which is supposed to retrieve the RSS feed from a URL

```
        public void GetRSS(string url)
    {
        // Connect to the web server
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        // Set the HTTP properties
        wr.Timeout = 9000;

        // Read the Response
        WebResponse resp = wr.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();

        // Load XML Document
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        reader.XmlResolver = null;

        xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load(reader);

        //Select the "RSS items" from the feed
        XmlNodeList items = xml.SelectNodes("//item");

        //Open a serializer
        XmlSerializer serializer =
                new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rss));

        using (XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml.OuterXml)))
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            rss = (Rss)new XmlSerializer(typeof(Rss)).Deserialize(xreader);
        }

        resp.Close();

    }
```

This always throws "System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out" on the line

```
WebResponse resp = wr.GetResponse();
```

My issue is that I cannot see why exactly this isn't working. I assume that no connection can be made to the URL, but no matter how many URLs I try, it never works. It just hangs for a few seconds and then comes up with the error.

To clarify, the program executes flawlessly on every machine I have tried it on aside from my home computer, on which I need to write the program.

Comment: Do you have a software firewall on your computer that may be blocking web traffic from sources it doesn't recognize?  If you have a firewall, try disabling before you run.

Comment: This looks like a connectivity issue since the same code runs on other machines. What will happen if you type the URL in the browser?

Comment: I disabled my firewall and the issue still occurs. I am able to access  every URL I have tried in the browser, just not through the application.